# Julia: Efficiently map zipped tuples to Tuple

Tags: performance, julia

I am looking for an efficient way to `map` some form of zipped tuples such that the result is a `Tuple` without heap allocations.

To be clear: I'm happy with not using `zip`. Any solution that allows to iterate jointly over multiple tuples would do, as long as it avoids heap allocations.

Example:

```
a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
b = ("a", "b", "c", "d")

# Just placeholder for an arbitrary non-allocating operation with i and j
do_something(i,j) = (i,j)

# Naive construction `Tuple` from resulting `Array` will allocate.  
c1 = map(zip(a, b)) do (i, j)
    do_something(i,j)
end |> Tuple

# Naive conversion to `Tuple` before mapping will allocate.
c2 = map(Tuple(zip(a, b))) do (i, j)
    do_something(i,j)
end
```

Both `c1` and `c2` will be of the desired type. However, in any case this will allocate memory. What is a good way to do this in an efficient manner?

Comment: Perhaps the most important question is, why are you unhappy with `zip`?

Comment: `zip` would be good if the output of `map` would still be a tuple. However, mapping zipped tuples will give an `Array` which I can convert to a `Tuple` but it allocates . I think something that would help would be a version of `map` that takes the desired output type as an input or a "static" version of `zip`, such that the input to `map` is a `Tuple` of tuples.

Comment: Got it! See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying something like

```
julia> map((i,j)->(i,j), a, b)
((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d"))
```

Or for a more interesting example,

```
julia> map((i,j)->j^i, a, b)
("a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was not aware that one can hand multiple collections to map like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if `a` and `b` are arrays rather than tuples. See the example below:

```
julia> a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

julia> b1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

julia> z = do_something.(view.(Ref(a1),1:4),  view.(Ref(b1),1:4))
4-element Array{Tuple{SubArray{Int64,0,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{Int64},true},SubArray{String,0,Array{String,1},Tuple{Int64},true}},1}:
 (1, "a")
 (2, "b")
 (3, "c")
 (4, "d")
```

Comment: with a small amount of elements, this allocates a lot, but i think this can be better with more elements.

Comment: it allocates memory references only. So if `a1` and `b1` have large elements this should be fine.

Comment: In my setting, `a` and `b` have rather few elements (which is why they are `Tuples` and not `Arrays`. But there might be a way with `StaticArrays.SVector` as these are essentially tuples implementing the array interface.

Answer (score 0):

this code will only work if `f(a,b)` produces the same type for every element of the tuple, and two elements only (but it can be modified to suit your operation):

```
function mytuplemaker(f,a,b)
if (len=length(a)) == length(b) #asigns len and compares at the same time, neat trick
    x1 = f(a[1],b[1]) #wastes a calculation to obtain the resulting type
    T = typeof(x1) 
    return NTuple{len,T}(f(a[i],b[i]) for i = 1:len)
else
    return nothing
end
end
```

some benchmarks:

```
julia> @btime map(Tuple(zip($a, $b))) do (i, j)
           do_something(i,j)
       end
  377.340 ns (13 allocations: 528 bytes)
((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d"))
```

```
@btime  map(zip($a, $b)) do (i, j)
           do_something(i,j)
       end |> Tuple
  377.223 ns (10 allocations: 480 bytes)
((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d"))
```

```
@btime mytuplemaker(do_something,$a,$b)
  38.655 ns (5 allocations: 176 bytes)
((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d"))
```

its 5 allocations, one per element +1 for the wasted one

Comment: `a[i]` and `b[i]` will copy Tuple elements

Comment: when using `@btime` you should write `$a, $b` instead of `a, b` otherwise you are measuring compiler's time and effort for handling the global variables.